# Puppeteer js attempting to get value of data-src in img tag

Tags: puppeteer

Currently I have the following HTML:

I'm needing to get the data-src link that is there.  My code in puppeteer js is:

```
  await page.waitForSelector('#ldpPhotoGallery');
  const getImgSrc = await page.$$eval('#ldpPhotoGallery', imgs => imgs.map(img => {img.getAttribute('data-src')}));
  console.log(getImgSrc);
```

Here I wait for the page id then after it's loaded it should run the page evaluation.  I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.  From what I understand I'm evaluation the id ldpPhotoGallery then from there it returns the contents.  From there I'm searchinging getAttribute data-src and it should return it no?  The console.log is [null].  I know the data is there.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just have a typo in the arrow function format: `.map(img => {img.getAttribute('data-src')})` would fill all the array with `undefined`, as an arrow functiond body in curly brackets without `retutn` implicitly returns `undefined`. Then `undefined` is serialized as `null` and you get `[null]`. Just remove curly brackets or add explicit `retutn`.

BTW, you need not `page.$$eval()` for id selector, it returns an array with just one element. `page.$eval()` may suffice:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#ldpPhotoGallery');
const getImgSrc = await page.$eval('#ldpPhotoGallery', img => img.getAttribute('data-src'));
console.log(getImgSrc);
```

Comment: The above code returns null for me also.  Any ideas?  @vsemozhetbyt

Comment: Can you provide a small full script with the URL to reproduce the issue?